# Passing optional callback functions with parameters

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I'm trying in different ways to create a small scrolling method which can take an optional effect callback function. Imagine I can run scrollToEl(el, flash) which would first scroll down to the element and the flash it. How would I normally go about this?

This is what I've done..but it's not really working.

```
scrollToEl : function(el, callback) {
    // flash the selected product
    var self = this;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: el.offset().top - 50
    }, 1000, 'swing', callback); // how to pass el here as well paired with callback?
}

flash : function(el) {
    // flash the selected product
    el.animate({
        opacity : 0.4
    }, 100, 'swing', function() {
        el.animate({
            opacity : 1
        }, 1000, 'swing');
     });
},
```

I want to use it like this:

```
var el = $('#element');
scrollToEl(el, flash); // how to pass in to the callback function flash?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a closure:

```
scrollToEl : function(el, callback) {
    // flash the selected product
    var self = this;

    // Get completion callback if any
    var completion;
    if (callback) {
        completion = function() {
            callback(el); // See below if you prefer `el` to be `this` in the callback
        };
    }
    else {
        completion = $.noop;
    }
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: el.offset().top - 50
    }, 1000, 'swing', completion);
}
```

More about closures: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

If you want the callback to receive the element as `this`, you can use [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) instead of your own wrapper function:

```
scrollToEl : function(el, callback) {
    // flash the selected product
    var self = this;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: el.offset().top - 50
    }, 1000, 'swing', callback ? $.proxy(callback, el) : $.noop);
}
```

It comes to the same thing, because `proxy` creates a function. But it doesn't introduce a closure over the context of the call to `scrollToEl`.

Comment: Yeah, that is a good solution which I've also considered. Two things though:
1. I'd want the callback to be optional, so If i don't pass it I don't want it to be called either.
2. I'd love to see a way just passing the function, maybe using call or apply? I'm not so used to the functional aspects of the language

Comment: @Yonder: 1. In that case, you'd just make it optional. 2. You can use `call` if you like, but you still have to put the call in a function. You can do that yourself, or you can use `jQuery.proxy` to do it. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Neat! I didn't know you could use proxy like that. $.noop is a nice shorthand for the function() {} too, thanks!

Comment: @Yonder note that `$.proxy` is just a wrapper function that also happens to create a closure.

Answer (score 2):

It would be more normal for a callback to have the affected element as `this` rather than as a parameter:

```
flash : function() {
    // flash the selected product
    $(this).animate({
        opacity : 0.4
    }, 100, 'swing', function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity : 1
        }, 1000, 'swing');
     });
}
```

and then use a closure that uses `.call` or `.apply` to bind `el` to `this` when it's invoked:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: el.offset().top - 50
}, 1000, 'swing', callback ? function() {
    callback.call(el);
} : undefined);
```

Comment: Ah yea, something like this I was after - I agree - much better to use 'this'. How would you make the callback optional?